# how to convert a dynamically numerical string into a dynamically array of integers

Tags: c

```
struct integer* convert_integer(char* stringInt)
{
   struct integer* convertedInt_1;

   char* stringArray3 = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char));;

   free(stringArray3);

   stringArray3 = stringInt;
   convertedInt_1->digits = atoi(stringArray3);

   stringArray4 = stringInt;


}
```

this is a sample of the code. this code is giving me an error when i use the standard library from c "Warning: assignment makes pointer from integer to without a cast"

so i need to know how to convert a dynamically numerical string into dynimacally struct integer

Comment: Why are you allocating memory and then immediately freeing it?

Comment: Get a novice C book and read it. You are way out of your depth here.

Comment: What is the definition of struct integer?

Comment: `member for 4 months, 10 Questions, 0 Accepted Answers, 0 votes cast` You definitely need to improve your acceptance and voting rate.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any dynamic allocation for char string here, nor do you need an additional `char *` pointer.

```
struct integer* convert_integer(char* stringInt)
{

   /*Allocate memory to structure,You cannot return pointer to local structure*/
   struct integer* convertedInt_1 = (struct integer*)malloc(sizeof(*convertedInt_1));

   /*Convert the string to integer*/
   int i = atoi(stringInt);

   /*Assign converted integer to structure member*/
   convertedInt_1->digits = i; 

   /*return pointer to heap allocated structure*/
   return convertedInt_1 ;

}
```

Comment: `(struct integer*)` cast on `malloc` return value is spurious, otherwise this is pretty much all that can be done with this Q  +1

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with this code, but I'll try to walk you through them.

One, you `malloc` only one `char` worth of memory, not the amount of memory needed to hold your array. You really need to include an argument for the size of the array to be changed if the string is not null terminated.

Second, you're trying to use memory after you `free` it. This is bad. Very bad. You should only free memory after you're finished with it.

Next, you're trying to `atoi` the entire array at once. This is going to try to change the entire string into one number, not one `int`.

What I *think* you want, is to convert each character from stringInt to a (single digit) int in your result. For this, use a for loop to iterate through the array.

I'm pretty sure you want to be using `int` and not `integer`.

Last, you forgot to return anything - this doesn't compile.

Comment: There's no use of memory after free here. There is use of an uninitialized pointer though.

Comment: Forgive me my imprecise terminolgy :)